# ¿Cómo bloquear el ingreso de otros valores?

Tags: c++, entrada

Necesito bloquear el ingreso de letras y simbolos donde los numeros y de numeros y simbolos donde los caracteres

Ejemplo:

- Ingreso Max pero no quiero recibir números o algun símbolo.
- Ingreso 0987563421 como un telefono pero no deseo recibir letras ni símbolos.

Este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    char n[21], a[21], c[13], tel[13], us[21], co[21];
    cout <<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t                   Tricell S.A." << endl;
    cout <<"\t\t\t\t                <---------------->" << endl;
    cout <<"\n\t\t\t\t        > Ingrese sus nombres: ";
    cin.ignore(1,'\n');
    cin.get(n, 21);
    cout <<"\n\t\t\t\t        > Ingrese sus apellidos: ";
    cin.ignore(1,'\n');
    cin.get(a, 21);
    cout <<"\n\t\t\t\t        > Ingrese su cedula: ";
    cin.ignore(1,'\n');
    cin.get(c, 13);
    cout <<"\n\t\t\t\t        > Ingrese su telefono: ";
    cin.ignore(1,'\n');
    cin.get(tel, 13);
    cout <<"\n\t\t\t\t        > Ingrese un usuario: ";
    cin.ignore(1,'\n');
    cin.get(us, 21);
    cout <<"\n\t\t\t\t        > Ingrese una contrase"<<char(164)<<"a: ";
    cin.ignore(1,'\n');
    cin.get(co, 21);
    cout <<"\n\t\t\t\t        < Datos registrados correctamente\n\n";
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

¿Conocen alguna funcion o librería para bloquear caracteres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el que tenga el mismo problema o quiera una solucion esta fue la que encontre y probe:

Se crean dos funciones:

1.- `void editable (char *p);` que sera la funcion que bloqueara los caracteres del teclado

```
y su codigo es:

void editable (char *p)
{

//TAM es una variable que determina el limite de caracteres a ingresar

    int i, TAM=16;
    char tecla;
    i = 0;
    p[0] = '\0';
    do
    {
        tecla = getch ();
        if ( i > 0 && tecla == 8 )
        {
            cout<<"\b \b";
            p[--i] = '\0';
        }
        else
        {

        //En esta seccion es en la que se edita el bloqueo de caracteres (codigo ASCII)

            if ( (tecla >= 48 && tecla <= 57) || (tecla >= 65 && tecla <= 95)  || (tecla >= 97 && tecla <= 122) )
            {
                cout<<tecla;
                p[i++] = tecla;
            }
        }
    } while ((tecla != 13 || p[0] == '\0') && i < TAM);

    p[i] = '\0';
    return ;
}
```

2.- `char getch ();` que sera la funcion que capturara un caracter sin imprimirlo en el estandar de c++ no existe conio.h asi que hay que crear la funcion

```
char getch ()
{
    char car;
    DWORD leidos, modo;

    GetConsoleMode ( GetStdHandle (STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &modo );
    SetConsoleMode ( GetStdHandle (STD_INPUT_HANDLE), modo & 
                     !ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT & !ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT );
    ReadConsole ( GetStdHandle (STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &car, 1, &leidos, NULL );
    SetConsoleMode ( GetStdHandle (STD_INPUT_HANDLE), modo );
    return car;  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Ten en cuenta que los números de teléfono pueden contener caracteres que no son numéricos, como el símbolo `+`: `+34654321012` es equivalente a `0034654321012`. Por otro lado, en los nombres de personas puedes encontrar números u otros caracteres, como la periodista [Jennifer 8. Lee](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_8._Lee) o el sueco [Brfxxccxxmnpcccclllmmnprxvclmnckssqlbb11116](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brfxxccxxmnpcccclllmmnprxvclmnckssqlbb11116).

---

<strike>Si quieres ignorar ciertos valores de la lectura estándar puedes usar [`ignore`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore), así pues para ignorar números al ingresar letras</strike> Podrías filtrar los valores que te interesan (e ignorar el resto) discriminando entre números y letras:

```
std::string s{};
std::string::value_type c{};

// Leemos caracter a caracter
while (std::cin.get(c))
    // Si el caracter es alfabetico...
    if (std::isalpha(c))
        // ... agregamos el caracter a nuestro string.
        s.push_back(c);
```

Con [`isalpha`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) puedes determinar si un caracter es alfabético o numérico.

Puedes ver el código funcionando [[aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Eua62hDuqkiZiu8P).

Comment: Hola, una consulta, en qué parte de tu código utilizas la función `ignore`?

Comment: No la utilizo en ningún sitio @Xam ha sido un despiste tremendo por mi parte... en realidad, con la solución que propongo, no es necesario usar `ignore`